# why use square root of epsilon as the small number

Tags: epsilon

This question may be independent of the language, but I saw [this post using R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/integer.html) mentions using square root of epsilon as the small number:

```
is.wholenumber <-
    function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
```

Why there's a square root `^0.5`? Any help's appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an R specific question. However, [this post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14355/choosing-epsilons) provides some answers to your question. Basically, it is a good rule of thumb to avoid loss of precision.

Comment: thank u @Anders Ellern Bilgrau I updated OP in consideration of that